# How to source a .js api inside of a google cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I've created a javascript script that will get information from this api. I'm trying to set this up inside of a google cloud function. I understand how you "require" or "import" a reference normally inside of a google cloud function, and even that you can make reference to a local file. When i downloaded the api.js from the source and try to reference it, i get "bomgarState is undefined" where bomgarState is the reference that i need. I understand that it is looking for a json when an api is being defined but i need to use the api.js. I know that this code can work,when you run this in collaboration with an html that sources said api, i have no problems. I have tried many different solutions such as "require(./api.js)", getting from url, and much more but am unsure if this is something that is supported at this point.

TLDR: can't make reference or source a javascript api inside of google cloud functions, had been sourcing using html, now that we moved to google cloud functions can't figure out how to make reference.

Answer (score 0):

For you to import dependencies and libraries to your Cloud Functions, there are some available options that you can take with JavaScript, but only while using Node.js - without Node it's not possible.

For example, as the documentation [Specifying dependencies in Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) indicates:

> A function is allowed to use external Node.js modules as well as local data. Dependencies in Node.js are managed with npm and expressed in a metadata file called `package.json`.

So, you can use with Node.js the `npm` to import your dependencies to your Cloud Functions.

Other options are indicated in the following posts from the Community - that I would recommend you to take a look at it - one, for example, would be using the 'gcloud' command to deploy your function. This way, it would upload and deploy with all files from your directory.

- [Google Cloud Functions include private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550163/google-cloud-functions-include-private-library)
- [How do I structure Cloud Functions for Firebase to deploy multiple functions from multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486278/how-do-i-structure-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-deploy-multiple-functions-fro)

I hope these articles help you, since they indicate the only available options, unfortunately, to upload dependencies on your Cloud Functions.